# Manual addition of host to know hosts list breaking the code in python script- How to resolve it?

Tags: python, scp

I have this code in my `python script` where  in I pass the `ip address` of a newly launched server and I am trying to `scp` a file upto that new server. Now since its a newly launched server so it's ip is not automatically added to the list of know hosts and it prompts me to add it and by the time I type yes the code results in error. When I execute the same code again with same ip then no error comes as the ip was just added in last execution.

I have added `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to not ask for prompt(and it does not ask for prompt) but it does not resolve the error.

```
def scp_script():

    try:
        cmd_txt = "scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no script_filename.txt root@" + server_ip + ":/home/"
        output = system(cmd_txt)
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        sys.exit(1)

    if output != 0:
        print('Error: ' + strerror(return_code) + ' \n')
        sys.exit(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    scp_script()
```

This script is called as a subprocess from another script. The error I get is :

```
root@: No such file or directory
Error: Unknown error 256
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: show code for `system()` function

Comment: something is wrong with `server_ip`... the error shows that `root@` is being interpreted as a filename by `scp`, maybe because `server_ip` has whitespace?

Comment: @xi_, I imagine it is os.system

Comment: @xi_ it is `os.system`

Comment: @isedev how can I check for whitespace?

Comment: trying using `print(cmd_txt)` after you set `cmd_txt` (before the call to `system`), see what the string looks like.

Comment: @user2966197, just strip() it off, also I would recommend using subprocess

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ok. will try strip. Also with `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` I see that even though it does not ask for manual prompt it does add the ip to list of known hosts. How can I prevent it from adding?

Comment: Your code does still ask me for a password, they only way it would not would be if there was an error, this may be useful http://askubuntu.com/a/385187/147355

Comment: @PadraicCunningham so I should add `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null` ?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham if I do `scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null file1.txt  root@123.45.67.89:/home/`, I still see `Warning: Permanently added '123.45.67.89' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.` How do I not make it to add?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think it will be better if I ask this on linux forum right?

Comment: @user2966197, try http://pastebin.com/fETSJ8PE